# Plotly dash in docker do not load assets

Tags: docker, plotly, wsgi, plotly-dash, waitress

I have a multi-page dash application that works as expected when running it locally with:

> waitress-serve --listen=0.0.0.0:80 web_app.wsgi:application

so all the assets within the assets folder loads correctly, the images ar loaded with `src=app.get_asset_url('xyz.png')` and have set `app.css.config.serve_locally` to `true`, as shown here everything loads [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJOTj.png)

But when loading the same app within a docker container the assets don't load [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jswVd.png) and so the local css don't load either.

Have checked the files and folders within docker and everything is were it is expected to be.

I guess I'm missing something somewhere but don't find what, any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /gtg_analytics-master
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:$INSTALL_PATH/web_app"
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY web_app $INSTALL_PATH/web_app
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
web_app:
image: patber/gtg:dev
build: .
command: >
  waitress-serve --listen=0.0.0.0:80
  web_app.wsgi:application
environment:
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
volumes:
  - '.:/web_app'
ports:
  - '80:80'
```

Comment: could you share how did you build the docker image?

Comment: Updated post with docker files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for the CSS files [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/assets-folder-not-found-in-docker/14673/9).

```
app.css.append_css({"external_url": "./assets/xyz.css"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the solution provided here is correct but you need to also add:

```
app.css.config.serve_locally = False
```

furthermore instead of append you can add the stylesheet by:

```
external_stylesheets=["./assets/stylesheet.css"]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't great, but if you need to serve things other than css you can also use the external sources options:

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    assets_external_path='http://your-external-assets-folder-url/'
)
```

I ran into this with an image, and that is the best (current = Jan 30 '20) solution I am aware of.