# RSConnect does not recognize assets for Python Dash application

Tags: python, css, rstudio, plotly-dash, rsconnect

I have my Python Dash application with some css assets.

For example, I want to have all my `dbc.Label()` **bold**, so I included in my `assets/style.css` this code:

```
.form-label {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

I see that assets affect desired changes when I run it locally, while after deployment in RSConnect all css assets are ignored. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706867/plotly-dash-in-docker-do-not-load-assets) discussion, since it looked similar for me, however, it did not help.

Does someone have any ideas about the causes of issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'dash-bootstrap-components' external stylesheets for some reason overrides my css assets in RSConnect.
I specified style as argument and this helps as workaround.

For example:

```
dbc.Label(label, style={'fontWeight': 'bold'})
```